# Angular2 Dynamic Component detect changes error deleting from nested components

Tags: angular, dynamic, components, removechild

Update:

I have tried putting in the EmitterEvent, which does resolve my issue however it then is executed on all click events.

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'bol-form',
    template: `
    <table class="styledTable" id="CommoditySection">
    <thead><th>Commodities</th></thead>
    <tr><td>
    <div id="commodities" (click) = "removeHandlingUnits($event)">

        <h5><a id="addHandlingUnits" (click)="addHandlingUnits(handlingUnitsCount, 0)">Add More Handling Units</a></h5>

        <dynamic-handling-component
            [componentHandlingData]="componentHandlingData"
            [componentHandlingData]="componentHandlingData"
            [removeComponent]="removeComponent">
        </dynamic-handling-component>

    </div>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
    `
    })

    export class App implements AfterContentInit {

    private handlingUnitsCount: number;
    private componentHandlingData = null;
    private componentCommoditiesData = null;
    private removeCommoditiesComponent = null;
    private removeComponent = null;


    constructor() {
        this.handlingUnitsCount = 0;
    }

    addHandlingUnits(unita, unitb) {

        if (unita == undefined ) {
            unita = this.handlingUnitsCount;
            unitb = 0;
        }

        this.sleep(unita * 50 + 10).then(() => {

            this.componentHandlingData = {
                component: HandlingComponent,
                inputs: {
                    handlingUnitsCount: unita,
                }
            };

            this.handlingUnitsCount += 1;
        });

    }

     removeHandlingUnits(id) {

        if (id == 0) {

             this.sleep(10).then(() => {
                this.removeComponent = {
                    toDelete: id,
                    allDelete: true,
                };
            });

             this.handlingUnitsCount = this.handlingUnitsCount - 1;
             this.componentHandlingData = null;
             this.componentCommoditiesData = null;

        } else {

            this.sleep(10).then(() => {
                this.removeComponent = {
                    toDelete: id,
                    allDelete: false,
                };
            });

             this.handlingUnitsCount = 0;
             this.componentHandlingData = null;
             this.componentCommoditiesData = null;

        }

     }


    ngAfterContentInit() {

        this.addHandlingUnits(0,0);

    }

    sleep (time) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
    }

    }

    @Component({
    selector: 'handling',
    template: `
    <div id="commod{{handlingUnitsCount}}" class = "commHeaderHandlingType">
        <label>Select type of Handling units </label><br class="mobileonly">
        <select id = "handingUnit{{handlingUnitsCount}}" class="form-control" name = "bdhdform{{handlingUnitsCount}}">
            <option value=" ">(--)</option>
            <option value="BAG">BAG</option>
            <option value="BAL">BALE</option>
            <option value="BBL">BARREL</option>
            <option value="BSK">BASKET</option>
            <option value="BIN">BIN</option>
            <option value="BOT">BOTTLE</option>
            <option value="BOX">BOX</option>
            <option value="BXT">BUCKET</option>
            <option value="BDL">BUNDLE</option>
            <option value="CAG">CAGE</option>
            <option value="CAN">CAN</option>
            <option value="CTN">CARTON</option>
            <option value="CAS">CASE</option>
            <option value="CNT">CONTAINER</option>
            <option value="COR">CORES</option>
            <option value="CRT">CRATE</option>
            <option value="CYL">CYLINDER</option>
            <option value="DRM">DRUM</option>
            <option value="DBK">DRY BULK</option>
            <option value="ENV">ENVELOPE</option>
            <option value="FKL">FORKLIFT</option>
            <option value="HRB">HNGERS/RCKS BXS</option>
            <option value="IBC">INTERMEDIATE BC</option>
            <option value="JAR">JAR</option>
            <option value="JUG">JUG</option>
            <option value="KEG">KEG</option>
            <option value="KIT">KIT</option>
            <option value="LBK">LIQUID BULK</option>
            <option value="PKG">PACKAGE</option>
            <option value="PCK">PACKED</option>
            <option value="PAL">PAIL</option>
            <option value="PLT">PALLET</option>
            <option value="PCS">PIECES</option>
            <option value="RCK">RACK</option>
            <option value="REL">REEL</option>
            <option value="ROL">ROLL</option>
            <option value="SWP">SHRINK WRAP PLT</option>
            <option value="SWS">SHRINK WRAP SKD</option>
            <option value="SKD">SKID</option>
            <option value="SLP">SLIP SHEET</option>
            <option value="TNK">TANKS</option>
            <option value="TOT">TOTE</option>
            <option value="TRL">TRAILER LOAD</option>
            <option value="TRY">TRAY</option>
            <option value="TUB">TUB</option>
            <option value="TBE">TUBE</option>
        </select>
        <label>Number of Units</label>
        <input name = "bdhdunit{{handlingUnitsCount}}" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5">
        <button id="removeHandlingUnits{{handlingUnitsCount}}" (click)="removeHandlingUnits(handlingUnitsCount)">X</button>
        <br>

        <div class = "seperatorDiv">------------------------------------</div>
        <br>

    </div>
    `
    })
    export default class HandlingComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    private handlingUnitsType:string;
    private handlingUnitsCount: number;
    private handlingUnitsRequested: number;
    private commoditiesCount: number;
    private componentHandlingData = null;
    private componentCommoditiesData = null;
    private removeComponent = null;

    @Output() click: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        this.handlingUnitsCount     = this.injector.get('handlingUnitsCount');
        this.handlingUnitsRequested = 0;
        this.handlingUnitsType = " ";
        this.commoditiesCount = 0;
    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
                //this.addCommodities(this.handlingUnitsCount, unitb);
    }

    addCommodities(handlingUnit, id) {

        this.sleep(20).then(() => {

        this.componentCommoditiesData = {
            component: CommoditiesComponent,
            inputs: {
                commoditiesCount: this.commoditiesCount,
                handlingUnitsCount: this.handlingUnitsCount,
            }
        };

        this.commoditiesCount += 1;

        });

        return false;

    }

     removeHandlingUnits(id) {

        this.click.emit(this.handlingUnitsCount);
        return false;
     }

     sleep (time) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
    }

    }

    let componentList = [];

    @Component({
    selector: 'dynamic-handling-component',
    entryComponents: [ HandlingComponent ], // Reference to the components must be here in order to dynamically create them
    template: `
    <div #dynamicHandlingComponentContainer></div>
    `,
    })
    export default class DynamicHandlingComponent {

    @ViewChild('dynamicHandlingComponentContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicHandlingComponentContainer: ViewContainerRef;

    // component: Class for the component you want to create
    // inputs: An object with key/value pairs mapped to input name/input value
    @Input() set componentHandlingData (data: {component: any, inputs: any }) {

        if (!data) {
            return;
        }

        // Inputs need to be in the following format to be resolved properly
        let inputProviders = Object.keys(data.inputs).map((inputName) => {return {provide: inputName, useValue: data.inputs[inputName]};});
        let resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);

        // We create an injector out of the data we want to pass down and this components injector
        let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedInputs, this.dynamicHandlingComponentContainer.injector);

        // We create a factory out of the component we want to create
        let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(data.component);

        // We create the component using the factory and the injector
        let component = factory.create(injector);

        // We insert the component into the dom container
        this.dynamicHandlingComponentContainer.insert(component.hostView, inputProviders[0].useValue);

        componentList[ inputProviders[0].useValue ] = component;

        // We can destroy the old component is we like by calling destroy
        //if (this.currentComponent) {
        //  this.currentComponent.destroy();
        //}

    }

    @Input() set removeComponent(data: { toDelete: any, allDelete: boolean }) {

            if (!data) {
                return;
            }

            if ( data.allDelete == true ) {

            for( var item = componentList.length - 1; item >= 0; item--) {

                if ( componentList[item] != "REMOVED" ) {
                    if ( ( componentList[item] != null ) && (componentList[item] != 1)) {
                        componentList[item].destroy();
                        componentList[item] = "REMOVED";
                    } else {
                        componentList[item] = "REMOVED";
                    }
                }
            }

            } else {

                if ( ( componentList[ data.toDelete ] != null ) && ( componentList[item] != "REMOVED" ) && ( componentList[item] != 1 ) ) {
                    componentList[ data.toDelete ].destroy();
                    componentList[ data.toDelete ] = "REMOVED";
                }

            }

    }

    constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

    }
    }
```

I am having an issue with dynamic components. While deleting components, I am getting `detectChanges` error. I have tried to add `detach()` before and after the `remove()` method.

Here is full working example of my issue https://embed.plnkr.co/4yB7ZBCyFp2don9l8N3n/

The main question I have is how can I get rid of that error so it doesn't break after removing a component.

I am new to angular2 so this might not be the best way to accomplish this. I was looking and it seems that using emitter for the button of the sub components is the right way to go. I was just having trouble with getting it to call the `remove()` from the main component.

`remove()` seems to work from the main component, but when inside another component it seems to have changes sent to parent dynamic component.

Here is the error thrown

> ng:///AppModule/CommoditiesComponent.ngfactory.js:88 ERROR Error:
>   ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges
>       at viewDestroyedError (unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9579)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:14413)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:13552)
>       at callViewAction (unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:13897)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:13829)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:13553)
>       at callViewAction (unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:13897)
>       at execEmbeddedViewsAction (unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:13855)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:13548)
>       at callViewAction (unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:13897)

Following is my code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'bol-form',
    template: `
    <table class="styledTable" id="CommoditySection" 
    (handlingDeleteEvent) = 
    "removeHandlingUnits(handlingUnitsCount)">
    <thead><th>Commodities</th></thead>
    <tr><td>
    <div id="commodities">

    <h5><a id="addHandlingUnits" 
   (click)="addHandlingUnits(handlingUnitsCount, 0)">Add More Handling Units</a></h5>

    <dynamic-handling-component
        [componentHandlingData]="componentHandlingData"
        [removeComponent]="removeComponent">
    </dynamic-handling-component>

</div>
</td></tr>
</table> 
`
})

export class App implements AfterContentInit {

    private handlingUnitsCount: number;
    private componentHandlingData = null;
    private componentCommoditiesData = null;
    private removeCommoditiesComponent = null;
    private removeComponent = null;


    constructor() {
    this.handlingUnitsCount = 0;
    }

    addHandlingUnits(unita, unitb) {

        if (unita == undefined ) {
            unita = this.handlingUnitsCount;
            unitb = 0;
        }

        this.sleep(unita * 50 + 10).then(() => {

            this.componentHandlingData = {
                component: HandlingComponent,
                inputs: {
                    handlingUnitsCount: unita,
                }
            };

            this.handlingUnitsCount += 1;
        });

   }

   removeHandlingUnits(id) {

    if (id == 0) {

         this.sleep(10).then(() => {
            this.removeComponent = {
                toDelete: id,
                allDelete: true,
            };
        });

         this.handlingUnitsCount = this.handlingUnitsCount - 1;
         this.componentHandlingData = null;
         this.componentCommoditiesData = null;

    } else {

        this.sleep(10).then(() => {
            this.removeComponent = {
                toDelete: id,
                allDelete: false,
            };
        });

         this.handlingUnitsCount = 0;
         this.componentHandlingData = null;
         this.componentCommoditiesData = null;

    }

 }

ngAfterContentInit() {

    this.addHandlingUnits(0,0);

}

sleep (time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

}

@Component({
    selector: 'handling',
    template: `
    <div id="commod{{handlingUnitsCount}}" class = "commHeaderHandlingType">
        <label>Select type of Handling units </label><br class="mobileonly">
        <select id = "handingUnit{{handlingUnitsCount}}" class="form-control" name = "bdhdform{{handlingUnitsCount}}">
            <option value=" ">(--)</option>
            <option value="BAG">BAG</option>
            <option value="BAL">BALE</option>
            <option value="BBL">BARREL</option>
            <option value="BSK">BASKET</option>
            <option value="BIN">BIN</option>
            <option value="BOT">BOTTLE</option>
            <option value="BOX">BOX</option>
            <option value="BXT">BUCKET</option>
            <option value="BDL">BUNDLE</option>
            <option value="CAG">CAGE</option>
            <option value="CAN">CAN</option>
            <option value="CTN">CARTON</option>
            <option value="CAS">CASE</option>
            <option value="CNT">CONTAINER</option>
            <option value="COR">CORES</option>
            <option value="CRT">CRATE</option>
            <option value="CYL">CYLINDER</option>
            <option value="DRM">DRUM</option>
            <option value="DBK">DRY BULK</option>
            <option value="ENV">ENVELOPE</option>
            <option value="FKL">FORKLIFT</option>
            <option value="HRB">HNGERS/RCKS BXS</option>
            <option value="IBC">INTERMEDIATE BC</option>
            <option value="JAR">JAR</option>
            <option value="JUG">JUG</option>
            <option value="KEG">KEG</option>
            <option value="KIT">KIT</option>
            <option value="LBK">LIQUID BULK</option>
            <option value="PKG">PACKAGE</option>
            <option value="PCK">PACKED</option>
            <option value="PAL">PAIL</option>
            <option value="PLT">PALLET</option>
            <option value="PCS">PIECES</option>
            <option value="RCK">RACK</option>
            <option value="REL">REEL</option>
            <option value="ROL">ROLL</option>
            <option value="SWP">SHRINK WRAP PLT</option>
            <option value="SWS">SHRINK WRAP SKD</option>
            <option value="SKD">SKID</option>
            <option value="SLP">SLIP SHEET</option>
            <option value="TNK">TANKS</option>
            <option value="TOT">TOTE</option>
            <option value="TRL">TRAILER LOAD</option>
            <option value="TRY">TRAY</option>
            <option value="TUB">TUB</option>
            <option value="TBE">TUBE</option>
        </select>
        <label>Number of Units</label>
        <input name = "bdhdunit{{handlingUnitsCount}}" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5">
        <button id="removeHandlingUnits{{handlingUnitsCount}}" (click)="removeHandlingUnits(handlingUnitsCount)">X</button>
        <br>

        <dynamic-handling-component
            [removeComponent]="removeComponent">
        </dynamic-handling-component>

        <dynamic-commodities-component
            [componentCommoditiesData]="componentCommoditiesData"
            [removeCommoditiesComponent]="removeCommoditiesComponent">
        </dynamic-commodities-component>

        <a id="addCommodities{{commoditiesCount}}" (click)="addCommodities( handlingUnitsCount, commoditiesCount )" href="">Add More Commodities to Handling Unit</a>
        <div class = "seperatorDiv">------------------------------------</div>
        <br>

</div>
    `
})
export default class HandlingComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    private handlingUnitsType:string;
    private handlingUnitsCount: number;
    private handlingUnitsRequested: number;
    private commoditiesCount: number;
    private componentHandlingData = null;
    private componentCommoditiesData = null;
    private removeComponent = null;

    @Output() handlingDeleteEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        this.handlingUnitsCount     = this.injector.get('handlingUnitsCount');
        this.handlingUnitsRequested = 0;
        this.handlingUnitsType = " ";
        this.commoditiesCount = 0;
    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
                //this.addCommodities(this.handlingUnitsCount, unitb);
    }

  addCommodities(handlingUnit, id) {

        this.sleep(20).then(() => {

        this.componentCommoditiesData = {
            component: CommoditiesComponent,
            inputs: {
                commoditiesCount: this.commoditiesCount,
                handlingUnitsCount: this.handlingUnitsCount,
            }
        };

        this.commoditiesCount += 1;

        });

        return false;

    }

     removeHandlingUnits(id) {

         this.sleep(10).then(() => {
            this.removeComponent = {
                toDelete: id,
                allDelete: false,
            };
        });
        return false;
     }

     sleep (time) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
    }

}

@Component({
    selector: 'commodities',
    template: `
    <div id = "commoditityLine{{handlingUnitsCount}}_{{commoditiesCount}}"  class="overflowdiv">



    <table class="bolCommTable">
        <tr>
            <td id = "commHeaderWeight">Weight</td>
            <td id = "commHeaderClass">Class</td>
            <td></td>
            <!-- <td id = "commHeaderRemove">Remove</td> -->
        </tr>
    <tr>

        <td id = "commHeaderWeight">
            <input name = "bdwgt{{handlingUnitsCount}}_{{commoditiesCount}}" type="text" size="5" maxlength="7" >
        </td>

        <td id = "commHeaderClass">
            <select name = "bdclss{{handlingUnitsCount}}_{{commoditiesCount}}" type="text" width="49px" style="width:49px;">
            <option value="0">(--)</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="55">55</option>
            <option value="60">60</option>
            <option value="65">65</option>
            <option value="70">70</option>
            <option value="77.5">77.5</option>
            <option value="85">85</option>
            <option value="92.5">92.5</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
            <option value="110">110</option>
            <option value="125">125</option>
            <option value="150">150</option>
            <option value="175">175</option>
            <option value="200">200</option>
            <option value="250">250</option>
            <option value="300">300</option>
            <option value="400">400</option>
            <option value="500">500</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <button (click)="removeCommodities(commoditiesCount)">X</button>
        </td>



    </tr>

    <dynamic-commodities-component
            [componentCommoditiesData]="componentCommoditiesData"
            [removeCommoditiesComponent]="removeCommoditiesComponent">
    </dynamic-commodities-component>


</table>

</div>
    `
})
export default class CommoditiesComponent {

    private commoditiesCount: number;
    private handlingUnitsCount: number;
    private componentCommoditiesData = null;
    private removeCommoditiesComponent = null;
    private bdwgt: string;
    private bdclss: string;

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        this.commoditiesCount   = this.injector.get('commoditiesCount');
        this.handlingUnitsCount = this.injector.get('handlingUnitsCount');
    }

    addCommodities( unita, unitb ) {

        var commoditiesCount = unitb;
        var handlingUnitsCount = unita;
        var bdwgt = this.bdwgt;
        var bdclss = this.bdclss;

        //this.sleep(unitb * 30 + (unita * 40)).then(() => {

        this.componentCommoditiesData = {
            component: CommoditiesComponent,
            inputs: {
                commoditiesCount: commoditiesCount,
                handlingUnitsCount: handlingUnitsCount,
            }
        };
        this.commoditiesCount += 1;
        //});
        return false;
    }

    removeCommodities(id) {

            this.sleep(10).then(() => {
                this.removeCommoditiesComponent = {
                    toDelete: id,
                    allDelete: false,
                };
            });

        this.componentCommoditiesData = null;
        this.commoditiesCount = this.commoditiesCount - 1;

        return false;

    }

    sleep (time) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
    }

}

let componentList = [];

@Component({
    selector: 'dynamic-handling-component',
    entryComponents: [ HandlingComponent ], // Reference to the components must be here in order to dynamically create them
    template: `
    <div #dynamicHandlingComponentContainer></div>
    `,
})
export default class DynamicHandlingComponent {

    @ViewChild('dynamicHandlingComponentContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicHandlingComponentContainer: ViewContainerRef;

    // component: Class for the component you want to create
    // inputs: An object with key/value pairs mapped to input name/input value
    @Input() set componentHandlingData (data: {component: any, inputs: any }) {

        if (!data) {
            return;
        }

        // Inputs need to be in the following format to be resolved properly
        let inputProviders = Object.keys(data.inputs).map((inputName) => {return {provide: inputName, useValue: data.inputs[inputName]};});
        let resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);

        // We create an injector out of the data we want to pass down and this components injector
        let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedInputs, this.dynamicHandlingComponentContainer.injector);

        // We create a factory out of the component we want to create
        let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(data.component);

        // We create the component using the factory and the injector
        let component = factory.create(injector);

        // We insert the component into the dom container
        this.dynamicHandlingComponentContainer.insert(component.hostView, inputProviders[0].useValue);

        componentList[ inputProviders[0].useValue ] = component;

        // We can destroy the old component is we like by calling destroy
        //if (this.currentComponent) {
        //  this.currentComponent.destroy();
        //}

    }

    @Input() set removeComponent(data: { toDelete: any, allDelete: boolean }) {

            if (!data) {
                return;
            }

            if ( data.allDelete == true ) {

            for( var item = componentList.length - 1; item >= 0; item--) {

                if ( componentList[item] != "REMOVED" ) {
                    if ( ( componentList[item] != null ) && (componentList[item] != 1)) {
                        componentList[item].destroy();
                        componentList[item] = "REMOVED";
                    } else {
                        componentList[item] = "REMOVED";
                    }
                }
            }

            } else {

                if ( ( componentList[ data.toDelete ] != null ) && ( componentList[item] != "REMOVED" ) && ( componentList[item] != 1 ) ) {
                    componentList[ data.toDelete ].destroy();
                    componentList[ data.toDelete ] = "REMOVED";
                }

            }

    }

    constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

    }
}

let componentList = [];
var index = 0;

@Component({
    selector: 'dynamic-commodities-component',
    entryComponents: [CommoditiesComponent ], // Reference to the components must be here in order to dynamically create them
    template: `
    <div #dynamicCommoditiesComponentContainer></div>
    `,
})
export default class DynamicCommoditiesComponent {

    @ViewChild('dynamicCommoditiesComponentContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicCommoditiesComponentContainer: ViewContainerRef;

    // component: Class for the component you want to create
    // inputs: An object with key/value pairs mapped to input name/input value
    @Input() set componentCommoditiesData (data: {component: any, inputs: any }) {

        if (!data) {
            return;
        }

        // Inputs need to be in the following format to be resolved properly
        let inputProviders = Object.keys(data.inputs).map((inputName) => {return {provide: inputName, useValue: data.inputs[inputName]};});
        let resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);

        // We create an injector out of the data we want to pass down and this components injector
        let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedInputs, this.dynamicCommoditiesComponentContainer.injector);

        // We create a factory out of the component we want to create
        let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(data.component);

        // We create the component using the factory and the injector
        let component = factory.create(injector);

        // We insert the component into the dom container
        this.dynamicCommoditiesComponentContainer.insert(component.hostView, inputProviders[0].useValue);

        componentList[index] = component;
        index = index + 1;

    }

    @Input() set removeCommoditiesComponent(data: { toDelete: any, allDelete: boolean }) {

            if (!data) {
                return;
            }

            if ( data.allDelete == true ) {

                for( var item = componentList.length - 1; item >= 0; item--) {

                    if ( componentList[item] != "REMOVED" ) {
                        if ( ( componentList[item] != null ) && (componentList[item] != 1)) {
                            componentList[item].destroy();
                            componentList[item] = "REMOVED";
                        } else {
                            componentList[item] = "REMOVED";
                        }
                    }
                }

            } else {

                if ( ( componentList[ data.toDelete ] != null ) && ( componentList[ data.toDelete ] != "REMOVED" ) && ( componentList[ data.toDelete ] != 1 ) ) {
                    componentList[ data.toDelete ].destroy();
                    componentList[ data.toDelete ] = "REMOVED";
                }

            }


    }

    constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    }
}
```